# PHP - Convert a string to a variable

Tags: php, string, type-conversion

I have a string like :

```
$string = 'my name is $1';
```

Is it possible to turn the $1 to a variable to do something like

```
$string = 'my name is $1';
$1 = 'Ted';
echo $string ;
```

output : 'my name is Ted'

Thanks !

Comment: I think you just have to use double quotes for you string to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
echo str_replace('$1',$1,$string);
```

Or replace the quote with double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function. Here is an example:

```
$number = 9;
$str = "Beijing";
printf("There are %u million bicycles in %s.",$number,$str);
```

This will translate to "There are 9 million bicycles in Beijing".

Answer (score 2):

```
$1 = "ted";

echo "my name is $1"; //double quotes includes variables
```